# failed to process manifest file (android app )

Tags: java, android, android-studio, manifest

I am tiring to build an android application and unable to resolve the error.
Below is my error messange :

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\...\AndroidStudioProjects\manager10\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:2: error: attribute android:pacakage not found.
     error: failed processing manifest.
```

my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.manager10"
    android:pacakage="com.example.manager10"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="32"
        android:targetSdkVersion="32" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <!-- xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"> -->
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:extractNativeLibs="false"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Manager10" >
       <!-- removed activity from here -->
        <service
            android:name="androidx.room.MultiInstanceInvalidationService"
            android:directBootAware="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.manager10.androidx-startup"
            android:exported="false" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.emoji2.text.EmojiCompatInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup" />
        </provider>

        <uses-library
            android:name="androidx.window.extensions"
            android:required="false" />
        <uses-library
            android:name="androidx.window.sidecar"
            android:required="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

my gradle build :

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.manager10'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.manager10"
        minSdk 32
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.0'

    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.core:core:1.8.0@aar"
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation "com.android.support:percent:23.0.0"


    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
}

//gradleEnterprise {
//    buildScan {
//        termsOfServiceUrl = "https://gradle.com/terms-of-service"
//        termsOfServiceAgree = "yes"
//    }
//}
```

android studio version :
Runtime version: 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.

tried to

1. include gradle enterprise
2. clean and rebuild
3. change minSDK and targetSDK to same value (32)

Comment: Look very closely at `android:pacakage`. Do you see the problem? Hint: check the spelling.

Comment: Also, where did this code come from? In modern android, `android:package` isn't a thing (even with the correct spelling). And you don't need `package`. It will be set by gradle during the manifest merging step.

Comment: In general, you shouldn't type the AndroidManifest.xml file yourself. You should generate it when you start a new project in Android Studio. From there you can edit it. Just be careful of typos.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thank you for your help. i removed the `android:pacakage`, but it still  doesn't work.

Comment: If you still need help, I need more information that "it doesn't work"